# How to connect docker stack container to another one by hostname?

Tags: docker, networking, devops, docker-network, docker-stack

I am deploying an app and database to the server via docker stack. I have to provide an app container with env variable of my database address: hostname and port. But docker stack makes container names dynamic, so I cannot reference by them. I am sure I will have only one single copy of database container. How can I do that?

Comment: From docs (https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#container-discovery): For most situations, you should connect to the service name, which is load-balanced and handled by all containers (“tasks”) backing the service. To get a list of all tasks backing the service, do a DNS lookup for tasks.<service-name>. If you keep long running database connections open, you definitly want to configure the endpoint mode to "dnsrr" for your db service, as it bypasses the vip, which times out after 900 second (see how to configre: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#endpoint_mode)